# sql / phpmyadmin use query result in another INSERT statement

Tags: sql, insert, phpmyadmin

I have a problem where I do not have direct access to the database and need to generate some SQL queries for the client to copy paste directly into the SQL query box in phpMyAdmin.

What I am trying to achieve is: (this syntax does not work)

```
SET @var1 = Select id FROM Table1 WHERE another_id = 'UNIQUEID';
INSERT INTO Table2 ('v1', 'v2') VALUES (@var1 , 'blahblah');
```

@var1 will always be a single string.

How can i go about doing this using only sql statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured it out, waited 1 hour, and only 5 views and no replies.

```
INSERT INTO Table2(v1, v2)
SELECT Table1.id, blahblah WHERE Table1.another_id = 'UNIQUEID';
```